# How to view recent CVS project changes in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, svn, version-control, cvs

Is there a way in Eclipse to view all recent changes of a project? Like in SVN, you can just go "view log" on a right-click menu of a folder. In CVS/Eclipse, I can only view history on a certain file. I am not able to see what files were changed in the last commit.  >.<''

Thank you!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't think it's supported through the standard Eclipse plugin.

There was a [sourceforge project](http://cvschangelog.sourceforge.net/) that tried to augment this functionality, not sure if it's still actively being maintained.

Comment: This question was also asked on SO here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7600830/26510 and it links to an updated version of this plugin that has more features.

Answer (score 11):

You could do diff based on time. See what changes have been committed during last couple days, for example.

It's rather awkward in Eclipse, but you can go into CVS Repositories view, click "Dates", enter the "from" date, and then navigate to project you want to find changes, choose "Compare With" and choose "to" date. And then you will see changes that happened during that time.

Answer (score 1):

I don't find nothing insiede the tool in Eclipse. I prefer to use [CommitMonitor](http://tools.tortoisesvn.net/CommitMonitor.html) to monitor SVN History of project (entire project, branch/s, tag/s). It runs in systemtray and advert you every  seconds.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in [this thread](http://dev.eclipse.org/mhonarc/lists/platform-cvs-dev/msg00348.html) or in the CVS FAQ:

"see what files were changed in the last commit":

Would that not be the equivalent of selecting the "`Compare With>Another Branch or Version`" operation from the context menu of the project ?

Comment: And if you could choose a previous COMMIT this would work great, but you can't. You can only choose versioned tags.

Answer (score 0):

Until I don't have plugin that can do the job from Eclipse, I use file history from the ROOT of the repository.

If You not see file history in ROOT then create it with

```
REPOSITORY_HOME\CVSROOT>echo>history
```

After that all actions on the repository will be saved in form:

```
u4f2c09af|dejanr|MyPC|src|1.5|Main.java|
```

Note:all users need to have rw rights to 'history' file

Answer (score -1):

right click on project team->synchronize repository

Answer (score -2):

Doing this turned out surprisingly simple for me:

- In *SVN Repositories* view, right click any directory, including repository root
- Pick *Show history* from the context menu
- Revisions will be shown in the *History* view, like *Show log* in Tortois

Comment: Which Eclipse version are you using?

Comment: Sorry, I just realized you made a comment a long time ago. I'm using Juno.

Comment: No worries. Some Team stuff was showing up in my project's context menu, but I had to select 'Share' to set it up for the history to work. Cheers.