# Eclipse CVS changelist

Tags: eclipse, cvs

Is there a way to see all the recently changed files in an eclipse project (including files recently changed by other CVS users)?
Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The History view just shows the change log for a single file; there is no view to show the change log for all files in a folder or project.

You need to use a different tool.

If you use [Maven](http://maven.apache.org/index.html), you can try the [changelog plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-changelog-plugin/).

If you use [WinCVS](http://cvsgui.sourceforge.net/), there is an option to generate a changelog.

If that's also no option, try [cvs2cl](http://www.debian-administration.org/article/Generating_a_ChangeLog_from_CVS_history).

Answer (score 14):

There is also an Eclipse changelog plugin here

http://code.google.com/a/eclipselabs.org/p/changelog/

Looks very similar to the one on sourceforge that @Grzegorz Oledzki has linked to.

I've ran it on eclipse 3.7 using the update site and it works without any problems. Looks like the project had an initial commit to svn around 6th Aug 2010

Comment: I just tried this now (Nov 19, 2012) using Eclipse Indigo, and it's better than the SourceForge one. It allows you to diff each file in the change log as well, which the SF one doesn't. To install it, just choose "Help | Install new software" in Eclipse, paste the update url into the "Work with" field (http://code.google.com/a/eclipselabs.org/p/changelog/) and click the check box next to the "Changelog" plugin that shows up in the list.

Comment: Tried this today (Feb 4, 2013) and works as advertised in previous comments, but the URL I had to use was (http://svn.codespot.com/a/eclipselabs.org/changelog/trunk/org.eclipselabs.changelog.update-site/)

Comment: This site is now coming up as "Could not find" when I try to install, though I've used it in the past. Is the URL no longer active?

Comment: @redeveloper I just noticed the same thing. I was able to work around it by copying the org.eclipselabs.changelog_1.0.2.201204231239.jar from the plugins folder of an older Eclipse installation into the new one.

Comment: @atraudes Thanks! This inspired me to try again. I didn't have an old workspace copy but found a version here: https://github.com/elie29/changelog/tree/master/org.eclipselabs.changelog.update-site
I zipped these files together, installed it as a plugin from a local archive location, and presto! My environment is IBM RAD 9.5 in case anyone else needs a CVS change log for RAD.

Comment: Still work in 2023!!! @redeveloper thanks for the explain

Answer (score 4):

Use Compare With -> Another Branch or version.  You can compare with any point in time, or if you are using tags, any tagged version.

Answer (score 2):

[CVS Change log plug-in](http://cvschangelog.sourceforge.net/) seems to be the match. But it seems pretty outdated.

Answer (score 0):

Synchronize view in Eclipse offers a sort of changelog of the most recent changes made to the current branch. You can even select a model which will shouw you changes grouped by a "changeset", with commit comment as a discriminator.

Answer (score -1):

DD,

Your question has a few angles. You need to check on a few places.

1. Open the Window/View/Navigator view.
2. Right-click on the top of the project. 
   2.a. If you want to see the changes of your coworkers without updating your code, do right-click, Team/Compare with latest from repository. You will be able to see the changes coming in, and your changes affecting them. Naturally, everybody needs to be on the same branch, and everybody else should have committed their changes.
   2.b. If you want to see the changes *updating* your code, do a right-click, and Update or do Team/Update. Again, be sure everybody has finished committing, and they did it to the same brach or trunk before doing the update. Keep reading, please...
3. Again, in your Navigator View, go to the top of the project, right-click, and do Team/Show History. You will see the versions grouped by commitment, so you will have to go to each commit, click on it, and see what files changed on each version.
4. You can track the changes of each file by walking through the history of the project, and see at the bottom or the side which files changed on each version. Double click on a file to see the compare with other version of the file.

Good luck! CVS and SVN can be frustrating even after you get a good hold of the concepts.

Luis

Comment: @joksy82, as far as I can remember, yes. But we abandoned CVS about 9 months ago, and I have no way to test it again. However, it does work that way in Subversion. You can track a project with CVS and SVN at the same time, so you might want to give it a shot.