# Eclipse local changes for project

Tags: java, eclipse, cvs

I can view local history of a single file with History View. But I need to see local changes for projects. I found [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2493016/eclipse-cvs-changelist/7600830#7600830) for remote changes. I need the same thing but for local changes.

Comment: I am very sure this was one of the major influence why people use version control

Answer (score 0):

if you are connected to a repository then it must be simple, please follow the following steps.
Right click on the project-->select team-->select show history.
This should do it.
If you don't have one then(pretty sure its not possible for entire project) you must consider getting one, i personally think github is useful

Comment: Unfortunately there is no menu "Show History" on the path you said. I have a repository and we are using CVS for version control.

Comment: As an alternative log in to your CVS account and you must be able to see it there

Comment: I think you need to put a plugin for cvs